# Access ImageView-Element from ListView

Tags: java, android

i am trying to Access ImageView elements from a custom ListView to change their background color. Accessing and working with the TextView is no problem. But really no idea how to that with ImageView. Appreciate any help.

The list is shown without any problems btw. So everything is OK with the adapter.

list_layout.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/friendIcon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#0d8fe1"
    android:src="@drawable/transparent_background_96x96" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friendName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activ_layout.xml (does it matter in this case anyway?)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        tools:context=".activities.FriendsActivity">


        <!-- Here we are defining ListView in our XML file-->
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Code from the Activity

```
//Declaring Array adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FriendsActivity.this,R.layout.friends_list_layout, R.id.friendName, FriendsActivity.arr);



 //Setting the android ListView's adapter to the newly created adapter
 mListView.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

 for(int i=0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++){

   //obviously wrong code. No idea how to iterate through the ListView and getting the backround color to change it

   ImageView iview = (ImageView) mListView.findViewById(R.id.friendIcon);
   iview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }
```

Comment: what do you want to do? Different background for each imageview or same ?

Comment: different background for each ImageView. I already have a function that creates color codes from a userid.

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so you need to write your own adapter instead of using `ArrayAdapter`.

Here is a good tutorial explaining how to implement one. http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter .

`WeatherAdapter.java` is the custom adapter and inside the class, `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method  is where each listview item is inflated. (it's called for every row of the listview like a loop)

You can access the imageview and textview for every row there and inflate it with the color you like. `position is the row number for the row it's inflating.

Comment: i reached my goal with this tutorial [link](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)

Comment: But writing your own adapter is the right way. So I accepted this answer.
If someone reads your answer + the link in my previous comment, they will find a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: great! The tutorial was just to show an example. Glad you found what works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, What you are doing is only adding content to the ListView from a string array.

And I believe the only way to be able to access each imageview is to create a custom Adapter (or even use a RecyclerView with a custom ViewHolder) and implement a getter method or a listener.